# Drupal 7 default Forum styling for custom content type?

Tags: 7, comments, nodes

Im using Drupal 7's forum module. Its working great but I need to also make a custom content type a forum.

I can allow comments on this custom content type, but can I make it have the same styling as the default forum content type?

UPDATE - The reason I need this is there are 2 user roles. Only registered users can see forums at all. Users with a special role can see private forums aswell.

Comment: Why dont you just edit the forum content type?

Comment: How do you mean? What I need is 2 different content types, both as forums. At the moment I can only get D7's default forum styling to be applied to the default forum content type. Thanks

Comment: Im assuming you want to add extra fields to the forum, maybe Im wrong. If so just add those fields to the default forum content type. I guess I cant see why you would need more than one forum content types when you can categorize them with taxonomy or extra fields. You probably should extend your question with the use case.

Comment: Exactly, it sounds like you need a content access module that probably limits the access by taxonomy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 'have the same styling', I'm assuming what you mean is have the same structure and functionality as the Drupal core forum (i.e. threaded discussions). You can always modify the content template to match the same layout and css styling of the core forum module but just enabling comments won't give you the same functionality as forums. The forums module [uses comments but adds another layer](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/forum) of management on top which is where you get your threaded discussion. A comments-only content-type would also not integrate with forum add-ons like [Advanced Forum](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum).

You're best option is to create two distinct forums and then (as @frazras notes) use [Forum Access module](http://drupal.org/project/forum_access/) to control access based on your criteria.

Comment: Your method requires 2 levels of forums, the top level tags being 'open' and 'closed'. Im using the Hierarchical Select module to limit selections to the 2nd level. Thanks